# How to get only specific properties for multiple keys with RedisJson MGET?

Tags: redis, redisjson

I would like to get only specific properties of multiple RedisJson objects stored in the DB.

For example, 2 RedisJson were created:

```
JSON.SET Cat:1 . '{"name":"Mitzi", "color":"pink", "age":1}'
JSON.SET Cat:2 . '{"name":"Lucky", "color":"black", "age":13}'
```

We are interested to get only properties "name" and "color"
For a single object this would work:

```
JSON.GET Cat:1 .name .color
```

returns:

```
"{\".name\":\"Mitzi\",\".color\":\"pink\"}"
```

However, for multiple objects using MGET.

```
JSON.MGET Cat:1 Cat:2 .name .color
```

This obviously doesn't work, didn't figure out how to specify the properties as command arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
redis> JSON.MGET Cat:1 Cat:2 '$["name","color"]'
["Mitzi","pink"]
["Lucky","black"]
```

Comment: Another question on this, is there a method that will return also JSON properties names? As in case of missing properties we won't know which property the value belongs to. For example: JSON.MGET Cat:1 Cat:2 '$["name", "food", "color"]' will return the same result

Comment: @marina not yet. Please follow https://github.com/RedisJSON/RedisJSON/issues/955